# What exactly is incoherent about an infinite regress of contingent universes?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

After asking my chemistry teacher, about how a particular model of the Big Bang violates the Law of Conservation of Mass, he told a more coherent take on the Big Bang is to assume that there was a universe before our current one. Almost cyclical if that's a precise word. But those who uphold this view, also presuppose that the general concept of the universe is eternal despite being contingent.

This leads to an infinite regress of  contingent universes. Intuitively, this is logically garbled, but I have never received a good reason as to why this is incoherent. I heard that this infinite regress of contingent universes becomes reducible to non-existence because there would have never been an instance in which this began to exist. But when this applicable to God, then there's an issue. Any answers?

Comment: Not incoherent; could be just universal churn.

Comment: Nothing, unless one simply disallows "infinite regress" by decree. An infinite sequence of cycles starting with Big Bangs and ending with Big Crunches is perfectly coherent, and there is no violation of conservation laws in it (however, it is contradicted by the current cosmology that predicts a Big Reap instead of Big Crunch). It does not "become reducible to non-existence" simply because there is no time instant when it begins to exist. It just exists eternally. What does "when this applicable to God, then there's an issue" mean? What issue?

Comment: In the theory of a succession of expansion contraction cycle, there is no infinite regress of several universes, it's the same universe all along (like a piece of paper that gets crumpled, then flat again in cycles: it's always the same piece of paper). Also it's not established that the universe is contingent (and probably even not establishable). AFAIK "why is there something rather than nothing?" is not a settled question.

Comment: Eastern philosophies of both Hindusim and Buddhism assert that time is endless in both directions and that the universe goes through cycles, called kalpas, eternally.

Answer (score 1):

A cyclic universe does not really get at the underlying issue here, which is in my opinion, did the universe come into existence. A cyclic succession of universes may still be *a* universe with cyclicity. And just like a [directed cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph#Directed_cycle_graph) may repeat infinitely, yet something else may have brought it into existence.

Without the metaphysics of a universe bringing *itself* into existence settled, we are forced to turn to more stable footing, scientific theories. Since the big bang is a scientific concept, and "[[a]ny description of physical conditions “before the big bang” must be based on a theory that supersedes GR](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cosmology/)", and we don't have a scientific theory that supersedes GR, we are left to individuals' preferences of speculation.

Answer (score -1):

The beginning of the universe, might better be described as the simple, becoming more complex. And assuming every proton decays, & blackhole evaporates, it will eventually become 'simple' maximum chaos, photon soup. Complexity characteristically occurs *between* simple and chaotic. Penrose's Conformal Cyclic Cosmology proposes that the end of the universe is directly equivalent, topologically, to an unstable minimum entropy state: to the Big Bang.

It's a more recent thing to expect a Creation. Ancient Egyptian and Vedic cosmologies, the oldest we have records of, were cyclic.

> *I heard that this infinite regress of contingent universes becomes
> reducible to non-existence because there would have never been an
> instance in which this began to exist*

Why? It could have just always oscillated between simple and complex. The 'beginning' can be described as just, simple potentiality, a groundstate.

But the deeper question is, what is time? What does it mean to have a past, to have left records or traces? You could potentially recover everything we see, just from the uncertainty principle, with everything else as emergent from symmetries and symmetry breaking, including time-ordering. That's an appealingly elegant idea.

There are so many seemingly plausible and consistent models for before the Big Bang, see this [great Youtube series](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJ4zAUPI-qqqj2D8eSk7yoa4hnojoCR4m) for a taste.

Comment: It's polite to explain what you think is wrong with a post, when downvoting.

Comment: Anonymous cowardice is lamentable.